# неверный расчет значений в результате

Tags: python, python-3.x, float

Написал программу которая вычисляет ответ по x
Но когда проходит вычисление, она выдает неверное значение.

```
def start():
    x()

def resh():
    global a
    global b
    otv=11.3 * a - 9,4 * b
    print(otv)
    start()

def x():
    global a
    global b
    a = float(input('введите a:' ))
    b = float(input('введите b:' ))
    resh()
x()
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: вы чем пользуетесь, что у вас ошибки не выдаются? проверяйте свой код всегда хотя бы тут: http://pep8online.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

проблема здесь:

```
otv=11.3 * a - 9,4 * b
#               ^
```

место точки стоит запятая поэтому это вычисляется как два примера

```
11.3 * a - 9
4 * b
```

поменяйте запятую на точку и все заработает

ваш код лучше написать с помощью циклов

```
while True:
    a = float(input('введите a:' ))
    b = float(input('введите b:' ))
    print(11.3 * a - 9.4 * b)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!